# Export all Twilio programmable chat messages

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to export the contents of a chat channel in Twilio Programmable Chat for a client's records. Twilio limits to batches of 100 messages, however I can't figure out how to page through the results, i.e. get messages 101-200.

```
$messages = $twilio->chat->v2->services("my_service_id")->channels('my_channel_id')->messages->read([],100);
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on doing this in PHP either, but the above returns the first 100 messages of the channel.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the docs. Accepted argument list for the read() function [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/6.16.0/classes/Twilio_Rest_Api_V2010_Account_MessageList/read.html)

Solved with:

```
$messages = $twilio->chat->v2->services("my_service_id")->channels('my_channel_id')->messages->read([],null,20);
```

which returned all channels messages.